# Faulty Heroku API

Tags: python, node.js, heroku, deployment

const dynos = {
command: "python main.py",
type: "worker:",
};

const res_dynos = await heroku.post(`/apps/${res_app.id}/dynos`, {
body: dynos,
});

I'm using the Heroku API together with nodejs and when I run the code above it shows:
heroku python: can't open file '/app/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
What's the point of that? Why does the app appear? Is it possible to fix?